# Passing Regex results to a function

Tags: c#

I am trying to replace the values in a string at run time based on the contents within a set of braces.

```
// this.LinkUrl = "/accounts/{accountId}"
this.LinkUrl = Regex.Replace(account.Company.LinkUrl, @"\{(.*?)\}", "$1");
// this.LinkUrl = "/accounts/accountId"
```

So far it works as expected and removes the braces. But how can I pass the $1 value into a function, like so

```
this.LinkUrl = Regex.Replace(account.Company.LinkUrl, @"\{(.*?)\}", this.GetValueForFieldNamed("$1"));
```

So that "accountid" is replaced with the value the function returns? e.g. "/accounts/56"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a delegate to the `Regex.Replace` method that takes a `Match` and returns a string, e.g. define the function for replacement:

```
string GetValueForFieldNamed(Match m){
    string res = m.Groups[1].Value;
    //do stuff with res
    return res;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
LinkUrl = Regex.Replace(account.Company.LinkUrl, @"\{(.*?)\}", GetValueForFieldNamed);
```

Comment: Excellent, had to remove the {} from the `m.Groups[1].Value` but apart from that it works great.

Comment: That's a bit weird as this works well on my machine. Are you using the same regular expression? If I call `Regex.Replace("/accounts/{accountId}", @"\{(.*?)\}", GetValueForFieldNamed)`, then inside `GetValueForFieldNamed` I have `m.Groups[0].Value == "{accountID}"`, but `m.Groups[1].Value == "accountID"`.

Comment: That's my mistake, I was using index 0 instead of 1. Out of curiosity, why does it give 2 results?

Comment: The Groups object in Match always has at least one element. If the match was successful, then it contains the whole matched expression at index 0 and other groups at higher indexes (if there are any). If it wasn't successful, then it just contains an empty string at index 0. More at the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The `1st` Regex group in your pattern will be the `ID` you want, so you want to store it in a variable first, Then use your `GetValueForFieldNamed()` function and replace that `id` with the returned value:

```
var match = Regex.Match(account.Company.LinkUrl, @"\{(.*?)\}");
if (match.Success) {
    string id = match.Groups[1].Value;
    this.LinkUrl = Regex.Replace(account.Company.LinkUrl, String.Format(@"\{({0})\}", id), this.GetValueForFieldNamed(id));
}
```

Comment: Although I didn't specify that it could contain multiple {values} this answer would work for a single solution. So thank you.